# Coinbase Multisig

Tags: multisignature, coinbase

I accidentally created a multisig wallet (with a limit of 0) against my Eth wallet in my coinbase account and transferred some ETH there - now I can't get it out. Any idea how to either export that wallet or confirm transactions in coinbase